# XML Document Transform StackOverflowError

Tags: java, xml, dom, stack-overflow

I'm building an XML document from scratch. I wrote a class to insert and traverse the elements into the XML. This is it:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class XMLParser {

    private Document doc;
    private Node currentNode;

    public XMLParser(String path) {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            doc = builder.newDocument();
            currentNode = doc.createElement("Root");
            ((Element) currentNode).setAttribute("Path", path);
            doc.appendChild(currentNode);


        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public XMLParser add(String name){
        currentNode = currentNode.appendChild(doc.createElement(name));

        return this;
    }

    public XMLParser attr(String name, String value){
        ((Element) currentNode).setAttribute(name, value);

        return this;
    }

    public XMLParser set(String value){
        currentNode = currentNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));

        return this;
    }

    public XMLParser up(){
        currentNode = currentNode.getParentNode();

        return this;
    }

    public String toXML(){
        final Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        } catch (final TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3");
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            transformer.transform(
                new DOMSource(doc),
                new StreamResult(writer)
            );
        } catch (final TransformerException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }


}
```

Now I can make calls like "new XMLParser("").add("A").up().add("B").toXML();" to generate a String containing the XML Code.

This works great for smaller Documents, but if the xml is getting to large, I get an Stackoverflow-Error at transformer.transform(...) in toXML():

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
...[1000 lines in console buffer displayed]
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to minimize the stack overhead? I don't want to fiddle with the JVM settings, because I want it to run on different computers as well...

Thanks in advance for your ideas or solutions!

**Edit:**
Here is the recursive Code that gets called with an Java File Object of an directory that traverses the folders inside to build the xml-tree out of the contents of the directory

```
private void stepAhead(File f) throws IOException {
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        File[] ergebnis = f.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> dateien = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (File temp : ergebnis) {
            if (temp.isDirectory()){
                //System.out.println("Checking Directory: " + temp.getCanonicalFile());
                xml.add("Dir").attr("Name", temp.getName());
                stepAhead(temp);
                xml.up();
            }
            else if(temp.isFile()){
                dateien.add(temp);
            }
            else{
                throw new RuntimeException("Keine Datei und kein Ordner");
            }

        }
        for(File temp : dateien){
            BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(temp.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

            xml.add("File");
            xml.add("Name").set(temp.getName()).up();
            xml.add("Size").set(""+attributes.size()).up();
            xml.add("DateCreated").set(formatFileTime(attributes.creationTime())).up();
            xml.add("DateLastModified").set(formatFileTime(attributes.lastModifiedTime())).up();
            xml.up();
        }
    }
}
```

*xml* is the *XMLParser* object and i just initialze it in the constructor

Comment: A StackOverflow usually means there's something wrong in your code, not in the JVM configuration. Can you post the code that triggers the error?

Comment: I used an external library to build the xml before that was a wrapper around the xml/dom Java solution where i did not have the overflow.

I was thinking it was the transform, because if I remove the transform I won't get an result but it is finishing without an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with `XMLParser.set(String value)` and how you build the directory document:

`XMLParser.set(String value)` appends a text node and sets the current node to that text node.

Given your builder code in `stepAhead` you going down one level for the element and another level for the text node, but you are only going up one level.

```
xml.add("Name").set(temp.getName()).up();
```

The output is an incredible deep nested document when applied to deep directories full of files. The Transformer implementation uses recursion to traverse the document and then a stackoverflow occurs.

If you change `XMLParser.set(String value)` to

```
public XMLParser set(String value){
    currentNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
    return this;
}
```

everything works ok and the outputs look good. (You should have seen the screwed output when printing the result for a simple directory!)

Anyway XMLParser is a smart class, taking the pain out of DOM manipulation. Maybe it would better be named XMLBuilder.

Comment: Nice catch on the `set` implementation. Hint for OP: With that change, `currentNode` is always an `Element`, so rename and retype as `private Element currentElement`.

Comment: Thanks wero, you are my hero of tonight! the class is working and renamed.

Comment: @Andreas, appendChild() and getParentNode() still do return a Note, therefore i would have to cast in the other direction if even possible?!

Comment: @LukasE. `appendChild()` return "the node added", i.e. the parameter, so change your `add` method to `Element newElem = doc.createElement(name); currentElem.appendChild(newElem); currentElem = newElem;`. --- Yes, you have to cast on `getParentNode()`, but that eliminates the casts on `setAttribute` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Although it can be a bit more complex, use an `XMLStreamWriter`. This will allow streaming *infinitely large* XML files.

You will have to generate your own indentation logic, but heck, implementing details like that is why you have an `XMLParser` class, right? BTW, that should really be named `XMLGenerator` or `XMLBuilder`, don't you think?

To show how to use `XMLStreamWriter`, here's a little code to (mostly) uses your example (`new XMLParser("").add("A").up().add("B").toXML()`):

```java
XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
try {
    xmlStreamWriter.writeStartDocument();
    xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("\n");

    // <Root> ...
    xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("Root");
    xmlStreamWriter.writeAttribute("Path", "...");
    xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("\n");

        // <A x="abc">Hello World</A>
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("   ");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("A");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeAttribute("x", "abc");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("Hello World");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement(); // end of A
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("\n");

        // <B></B>
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("   ");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("B");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement(); // end of B
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("\n");

        // <C/>
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("   ");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeEmptyElement("C");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("\n");

    // </Root>
    xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement(); // end of Root

    xmlStreamWriter.writeEndDocument();
} finally {
    xmlStreamWriter.close();
}
```

**Output:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root Path="...">
   <A x="abc">Hello World</A>
   <B></B>
   <C/>
</Root>
```

Comment: thanks Andreas for your solution, wero had the right answer for me but the class is renamed and if i need it in the future I will step up to your idea